# Link between documents with anchor

Tags: python-sphinx

I have two rst document, like:

```
doc1.rst
doc2.rst
```

**doc1.rst**

```
Doc 1 content
*************

Foo bar
=======

baz !
```

**doc2.rst**

```
Doc 2 content
*************

You can see "foo bar" `here <doc1.html#foo-bar>`.
```

To have a link in doc2 to doc1#foo-bar i can hardcode it. But how do it without hardcoding? Can I do that with sphinx code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a label for the section in doc1.rst that you want to link to. Then use the [`:ref:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/referencing.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations) role to create a cross-reference to that section.

doc1.rst:

```
Doc 1 content
*************
 
.. _foobar:
 
Foo bar
=======
 
baz !
```

doc2.rst:

```
Doc 2 content
*************

You can see "foo bar" :ref:`here <foobar>`.
```

Answer (score 0):

With regards to internal links to known anchors, **doc1.rst** and **doc2.rst** do NOT have to be in the same folders, and you do NOT have to provide path information on where to locate the internal anchor `_foobar`.

**doc1.rst**

```
Doc 1 content
*************

.. _foobar:
```

**doc2.rst:**

```
Doc 2 content
*************

For additional details see :ref:`foobar`.
```

Note: References to internal links, such as to the anchor ***_foobar*** can be anywhere in the generated document space.  Both ***doc1.rst*** and ***doc2.rst*** can be anywhere in the document folder space, and Sphinx will find the appropriate anchor/label.  No path information needs to be provided on where to locate them.  But all anchors must be unique, throughout the generated set of documents.

https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/referencing.html#cross-referencing-arbitrary-locations